# Javascript code does not work in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari

I have code that works great on google crome, firefox, ... but it does not work in Safari browser.

What code does? It hide/show logo depends on the section that fixed element goes trought - it works but in Safari logo is just hidden.

Is there something that Safari does not supports?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {      

        $('#logoimode3').css({'display' : 'none'});

        $(function() { 
            var $window = $(window);

            var logo = $('#logoimode3'); 

            var div1 = $('#section1stran'); 
            var div2 = $('#section2stran');

            var div1_height = div1.height();
            var div2_height = div2.height();

            $window.on('scroll', function() { 
                var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
                var viewport_height = $window.height(); 
                var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;

              if (scrollTop >= div1_height  && (scrollTop_bottom <=  div1_height + div1_height + div2_height )) {
                    logo.css({'display' : 'block'});
                }
                else {
                    logo.css({'display' : 'none'});
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it.

Change:

```
$window.on('scroll', function() { 
                var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

To:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```